# Bootstrap 4 clear/reset validation after successful submit

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-4, reset

I use **Bootstrap 4** for validation of a 'Contact Me' form.

After successfully submitting the form I reset it with **`$('#contactForm').trigger("reset");`** which does clear the input fields, **but** these are still marked as validated (the validation icons and green borders are still there).

This causes a problem because I enable the Submit button only after validating all inputs, and disable it after submitting. But since the inputs are still marked as 'Valid', any valid entry in any of the fields will enable the button even though the other fields are empty (all fields are '*required*').

Please advise as to how to clear the validations after submitting the form. Thank you!

**IMPORTANT NOTE :**
I use *Bootstrap 4*. Not 3. I mention it because I went trough dozens of entries here in SO and elsewhere, and most answers refer to `bootstrap.validator` *which is **not** my case!*
Thanks again.

**My html:**

```
<div class="container"><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
      <form id="contactForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            Name<input  type="text" id="name" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z{1}[a-zA-Z-9 '\-]{1,29}$" required="required">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"><a>Error...</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            Mail<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}" required="required">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"><a>Error...</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            Phone<input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" pattern="^[0-9\+]{1}[0-9\-]{9,17}$" required="required">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"><a>Error...</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            Message<textarea type="text" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" required="required"></textarea>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"><a>Error...</a></div>
          </div><br>
          <div id="phpMailerResult"></div>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button id="sendMessageButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xl text-dark font-weight-bold">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My script :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ------------------------ Actions on SUBMIT     --------------------
  $('#sendMessageButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "mail/contact_me.php",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        message: message
      },
      cache: false,
      success:function() {
        $('#sendMessageButton').attr('disabled', true);
        var jsSuccess1 = "<div class='alert alert-success>";
        var jsSuccess2 = "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;";
        var jsSuccess3 = "</button>";
        var jsSuccess4 = "<strong>Message sent successfully!</strong>";
        var jsSuccess5 = "</div>";
        $('#phpMailerResult').html(jsSuccess1);
        $('#phpMailerResult > .alert-success').append(jsSuccess2, jsSuccess3, jsSuccess4, jsSuccess5);
        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
      },
      error:function() {
        $('#sendMessageButton').attr('disabled', true);
        var jsFail1 = "<div class='alert alert-danger>";
        var jsFail2 = "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;";
        var jsFail3 = "</button>";
        var jsFail4 = "<strong>Something went wrong...!</strong>";
        var jsFail5 = "</div>";
        $('#phpMailerResult').html(jsFail1);
        $('#phpMailerResult > .alert-danger').append(jsFail2, jsFail3, jsFail4, jsFail5);
      },
    });
    return true;
  });
  // ----------------- Validate  CONTACT form on input -----------------
  let jsContactForm = document.getElementById('contactForm');
  jsContactForm.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(jsContactInput => {
    jsContactInput.addEventListener(('input'), () => {
      if (jsContactInput.checkValidity()) {
        jsContactInput.classList.add('is-valid');
        jsContactInput.classList.remove('is-invalid');
      } else {
        jsContactInput.classList.add('is-invalid');
        jsContactInput.classList.remove('is-valid');
      }
      let jsIsValid = $(jsContactForm.querySelectorAll('.form-control')).length === $(jsContactForm.querySelectorAll('.form-control.is-valid')).length;
      if (jsIsValid) {
        $('#sendMessageButton').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('#sendMessageButton').attr('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am happy (and rather proud too) to have solved the problem myself!

In my 'Actions on SUBMIT' part of the script I added some lines (which I marked in the following snippet with **<===** so it is easier to see).

Now after successful submit, the input fields are cleared and not marked as valid neither as invalid, and so a new cycle of sending out the contact-me form can start fresh.

Here is the revised part of the code (the rest of the code was not changed) :

```
  // ------------------------ Actions on SUBMIT     --------------------
  $('#sendMessageButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#phpMailerResult').show();                      // <===
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "mail/contact_me.php",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        message: message
      },
      cache: false,
      success:function() {
        $('#sendMessageButton').attr('disabled', true);
        var jsSuccess1 = "<div class='alert alert-success myHeight22'>";
        var jsSuccess2 = "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;";
        var jsSuccess3 = "</button>";
        var jsSuccess4 = "<strong>Message sent successfully!</strong>";
        var jsSuccess5 = "</div>";
        $('#phpMailerResult').html(jsSuccess1);
        $('#phpMailerResult > .alert-success').append(jsSuccess2, jsSuccess3, jsSuccess4, jsSuccess5);
        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        let jsContactForm = document.getElementById('contactForm');                   // <=== 
        jsContactForm.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(jsContactInput => {   // <===
          jsContactInput.classList.remove('is-valid');                                // <===
          jsContactInput.classList.remove('is-invalid');                              // <===
          jsContactInput.addEventListener(('keyup'), () => {                          // <===
            $('#phpMailerResult').hide();                                             // <===
          });                                                                         // <===
        });                                                                           // <===
      },
      error:function() {
        $('#sendMessageButton').attr('disabled', true);
        var jsFail1 = "<div class='alert alert-danger myHeight22'>";
        var jsFail2 = "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;";
        var jsFail3 = "</button>";
        var jsFail4 = "<strong>Something went wrong...!</strong>";
        var jsFail5 = "</div>";
        $('#phpMailerResult').html(jsFail1);
        $('#phpMailerResult > .alert-danger').append(jsFail2, jsFail3, jsFail4, jsFail5);
      },
    });
    return true;
  });
```